# JQuery: DatePicker defaults

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a lot of JQuery DatePicker's in my application. How can I set to all this elements default settings/options?

```
$(function() {
        $( "#<%=dtIncident2.ClientID %>" ).datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "AppData/Images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            maxDate: '+0',
            regional: 'uk'
        });
    });
```

I don't want to set every time **showOn**, **buttonImage**, **buttonImageOnly**... and other options.

Comment: Where did you find the full list of optionName's? Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

did you even search for the answer before you asked? :P

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/setDefaults

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
   showOn: 'both',
   buttonImageOnly: true,
   buttonImage: 'calendar.gif',
   buttonText: 'Calendar' });
```

it's the first result when you google jquery ui datepicker set defaults.

Comment: +1 and this is the first result in so, which I find much more familiar than google results

Comment: Answer is still valid but the link is dead. Here is the right one : https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-functions